# Double values are not getting updated MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have been able to successfully update all other values in my table except for the double values longitude and latitude.  I do not see anything that I am doing wrong in this statement:

`update users set latitude = 28.49846411506931 and longitude = 81.53321456707519 where id = 1;`

There is a row with id = 1 and a table named users as well.

This is what is returned:

`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0`

Comment: The correct separator for updates is comma `,`, not `and`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `and`.

```
update users set latitude = 28.49846411506931, longitude = 81.53321456707519 where id = 1;
```